# Greedy regex does not pick the closest choice

Tags: regex

my regex does not pick the closest `[A]` What can be a solution for this case?

Input:

```
[A]xxx[A]yyyy[B]
```

Regex:

```
\[A\](?!\[A\])(.*?)\[B\]
```

Match:

```
[A]xxx[A]yyyy[B]
```

Match I need:

```
[A]yyyy[B]
```

Comment: Could you explain what you don't understand about the regex and the results?

Comment: Also, which language/tool are you doing this in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually close. The only issue is that the lookahead does not look all the way through the string by itself. It will only look at the current position. You can help it out though:

```
\[A\](?!.*\[A\])(.*?)\[B\]
```

If your input might contain multiple pairs of `[A]...[B]` (consecutively) and you want to match all of them, you can either go with Bohemian's answer, or use the more general approach (which will work for more complex exclusion patterns) and check the lookahead at every position:

```
 \[A\]((?:(?!\[A\]).)*+)\[B\]
```

This will only consume another character (`.`) if that character does not mark the beginning of an `[A]`. The `+` after the `*` makes the latter [possessive](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html), which is just an optimization applicable in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
\[A\][^A]+\[B\]
```

This ensures there are no A between the first A and B